# filtering data between time interval(10min) in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to filter data between two datetime values with interval(10 or 15min)

Suppose if I want data between '2014-10-14 00:00:00' and '2014-10-15 01:00:00' with 15min intervals then my output will return

```
2014-10-09   01:00:00   6624.067
2014-10-09   01:15:00   6623.666
2014-10-09   01:30:00   6626.044
2014-10-09   01:45:00   6624.261
2014-10-09   02:00:00   6622.448
2014-10-09   02:15:00   6616.236
2014-10-09   03:50:00   6607.514
2014-10-09   04:00:00   6614.486
```

Table structure is:

```
 LogDate   LogTime   machine_val   machine_id  

2014-10-09  01:00:00    6624.067  1
2014-10-09  01:05:00    6623.666  1
2014-10-09  01:10:00    6626.044  1
2014-10-09  01:00:00    6624.261  43 
2014-10-09  02:00:00    6622.448  7
2014-10-09  02:00:00    6616.236  5
2014-10-09  03:50:00    6607.514  1
2014-10-09  04:00:00    6614.486  2
```

I tried with grouping values

> group by date(logdate),hour(logtime),minute(logtime) div 15;

AND

> concat(LogDate,' ',LogTime)  >= DATE_SUB('2014-10-09 01:00:00', INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
>   AND concat(LogDate,' ',LogTime)  <= DATE_ADD('2014-10-10 01:00:00', INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)

but it is not returning correct values for the interval values like 10min,25min...etc.

Any suggestions

Comment: please post the structure of your tables and what summarization you want on your data. also show us what queries you tried.

Comment: You could try converting to UNIX time and then trying `x div 600` instead of `x div 10`

Comment: You could make a reference table(s) of the interval(s) you are interested in and cross join it.  I know there is probably some MySQL specific solution that is less labor intensive, but I've used this method in SQL Server before with good results.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714350/mysql-group-by-timestamp-every-15-minutes-including-missing-entries/29714667#29714667, although i really dont understand how your source gives you your desired response. @bf2020 there isn't a mysql easymode method - you either create the interval tables, or shove a messy union subquery in there.

Comment: @pala_ - +1 - that's a cool solution, thanks for referring me to it.  I'll definitely use that approach next time...

Comment: @shivu It is not clear what the third column of your result should be. Is it an average of the values in each range? a random value from each group?

Comment: Machine value from the table

Comment: and the value of which row do you want to show, if you select only one row each 15 mins?

Comment: value of machine_id  = 1

Answer (score 0):

You need date to be in valid date format.

```
set @d1 = '09/10/2014';
set @t1 = '01:00:00';

SELECT concat(
    RIGHT(@d1, 4), -- year
    '-',
    RIGHT(LEFT(@d1, 5), 2), -- mont
    '-',
    LEFT(@d1, 2), -- day
    ' ',
    @t1 -- time
) AS date1;
+---------------------+
| date1               |
+---------------------+
| 2014-10-09 01:00:00 |
+---------------------+

SELECT CONCAT(
    RIGHT(@d1, 4), -- year
    '-',
    RIGHT(LEFT(@d1, 5), 2), -- mont
    '-',
    LEFT(@d1, 2), -- day
    ' ',
    @t1 -- time
) +  INTERVAL 30 MINUTE AS date1Plus;
+---------------------+
| date1Plus           |
+---------------------+
| 2014-10-09 01:30:00 |
+---------------------+
```

it looks ugly, but it works...